# Get the rack to update after shuffle

Tags: flutter

[image]

In the example below, what is the best construct to use to get the rack to update after a shuffle?

It seems to me that when a StatefulWidget is created, with its corresponding State Object (SO), any method that you can call from elsewhere is a method that's attached to the widget itself (not to the SO).

But, to get the widget to update its display, the SetState() method can only go in the SO's method(s). So how does the method on the widget call a method on its SO?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<Block> g_blocks = [Block(Colors.red), Block(Colors.green), Block(Colors.blue)];
Rack g_rack = new Rack();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// This widget is the root of your application.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'PressStart',
      ),
      home: MyHomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  createState() => MyHomeScreenState();
}

class MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Thanks for your help')),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: g_rack,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: 100.0,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: 0,
          iconSize: 48.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[100],
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Shuffle',
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Shuffle',
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (int indexOfItem) {
            setState(() {
              g_blocks.shuffle;
              rack.updateScreen();  // ** How to get the rack to update? **
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }   // build
}   // End class MyHomeScreenState

class Rack extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _rackState createState() => _rackState();
}

class _rackState extends State<Rack> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150.0,
      color: Colors.yellow[200],
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: g_blocks),
    );
  }
  void updateRack(){
    setState(() {
      g_blocks.shuffle;
    });
  }
}

class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  Block(this.color);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(height:50,width:50, color: color,);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution where I try to decouple the State Management and Business Logic of the application from the User Interface.

[image]

I used the following packages:

- [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for the Domain Entities
- [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) for the State Management

---

### 1. Domain Layer: Entities

We need two Entities to model our `Racks` of `Blocks`.

- `Blocks` are defined by their `color`.
- `Blocks` have no business logic.
- `Racks` are ordered lists of `Blocks`.
- `Racks` can get `shuffled`.
- `Racks` can be randomly created for a (random or given) number of `Blocks`

```
@freezed
abstract class Block with _$Block {
  const factory Block({Color color}) = _Block;
}

@freezed
abstract class Rack implements _$Rack {
  const factory Rack({List<Block> blocks}) = _Rack;
  const Rack._();

  static Rack create([int nbBlocks]) => Rack(
        blocks: List.generate(
          nbBlocks ?? 4 + random.nextInt(6),
          (index) => Block(
            color: Color(0x66000000 + random.nextInt(0xffffff)),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Rack get shuffled => Rack(blocks: blocks..shuffle());
}
```

We use the [freeze package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) to have immutability and the precious `copyWith` method to manage our States.

---

### 2. Application Layer: State Management

We use [Hooks Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) for our State Management. We just need one StateNotifier and its provider.

This `StateNotifierProvider` gives access to both the `Rack` State and the core functionalities that are `deal()` and `shuffle()`.

```
class RackStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<Rack> {
  static final provider =
      StateNotifierProvider<RackStateNotifier>((ref) => RackStateNotifier());

  RackStateNotifier([Rack state]) : super(state ?? Rack.create());

  void shuffle() {
    state = state.shuffled;
  }

  void deal() {
    state = Rack.create();
  }
}
```

### 3. Presentation Layer: User Interface

The User Interface is made of four Widgets:

- `AppWidget` [StatelessWidget]
- `HomePage` [HookWidget]
- `RackWidget` [StatelessWidget]
- `BlockWidget` [StatelessWidget]

As you see, the only Widget that really cares about the State of the Application is the `HomePage`.

#### 3.1 AppWidget

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.amber,
        accentColor: Colors.black87,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 3.2 HomePage

```
class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final rack = useProvider(RackStateNotifier.provider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: const [
            Icon(Icons.casino_outlined),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8.0,
            ),
            Text('Rack Shuffler'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RackWidget(rack: rack),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              iconSize: 48,
              onPressed: () => context.read(RackStateNotifier.provider).deal(),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shuffle),
              iconSize: 48,
              onPressed: () =>
                  context.read(RackStateNotifier.provider).shuffle(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`rack` is provided by our StateNotifierProvider, in watch mode:

```
final rack = useProvider(RackStateNotifier.provider.state);
```

The `Racks` are dealt and shuffled using the same provider, in read mode:

```
...
context.read(RackStateNotifier.provider).deal(),
...
context.read(RackStateNotifier.provider).shuffle(),
...
```

#### 3.3 RackWidget

```
class RackWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Rack rack;

  const RackWidget({Key key, this.rack}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Row(
            children: rack.blocks
                .map((block) => BlockWidget(
                    block: block,
                    size: constraints.biggest.width / rack.blocks.length))
                .toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basic StatelessWidget. We use a LayoutBuilder to define the size of the `BlockWidgets`.

#### 3.4 BlockWidget

```
class BlockWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Block block;
  final double size;

  const BlockWidget({
    Key key,
    this.block,
    this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(size / 10),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: block.color,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: size / 20),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size / 15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Another basic StatelessWidget.

---

### Full Application Code

Just copy-paste the following to try it out.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

part '66053795.shuffle.freezed.dart';

Random random = Random();

void main() => runApp(ProviderScope(child: AppWidget()));

class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.amber,
        accentColor: Colors.black87,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final rack = useProvider(RackStateNotifier.provider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: const [
            Icon(Icons.casino_outlined),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8.0,
            ),
            Text('Rack Shuffler'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RackWidget(rack: rack),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              iconSize: 48,
              onPressed: () => context.read(RackStateNotifier.provider).deal(),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shuffle),
              iconSize: 48,
              onPressed: () =>
                  context.read(RackStateNotifier.provider).shuffle(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RackWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Rack rack;

  const RackWidget({Key key, this.rack}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Row(
            children: rack.blocks
                .map((block) => BlockWidget(
                    block: block,
                    size: constraints.biggest.width / rack.blocks.length))
                .toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Block block;
  final double size;

  const BlockWidget({
    Key key,
    this.block,
    this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(size / 10),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: block.color,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: size / 20),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size / 15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RackStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<Rack> {
  static final provider =
      StateNotifierProvider<RackStateNotifier>((ref) => RackStateNotifier());

  RackStateNotifier([Rack state]) : super(state ?? Rack.create());

  void shuffle() {
    state = state.shuffled;
  }

  void deal() {
    state = Rack.create();
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class Block with _$Block {
  const factory Block({Color color}) = _Block;
}

@freezed
abstract class Rack implements _$Rack {
  const factory Rack({List<Block> blocks}) = _Rack;
  const Rack._();

  static Rack create([int nbBlocks]) => Rack(
        blocks: List.generate(
          nbBlocks ?? 4 + random.nextInt(6),
          (index) => Block(
            color: Color(0x66000000 + random.nextInt(0xffffff)),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Rack get shuffled => Rack(blocks: blocks..shuffle());
}
```

Comment: Great answer. This is an excellent example of how to utilize freezed, state_notifier, flutter_hooks, and hooks_riverpod.

Comment: Agree - great answer, many thanks. I like the separation into Business Logic, UI, and State Management. I did come up with a solution using GlobalKeys, which I'll add below, but your solution is impressively rigorous & inspires further study.

Comment: @Thierry: I'm stumped by the bit in your code: "part '66053795.shuffle.freezed.dart';"  What does this do?

Comment: @user3012629 Have a look at the Freezed package (https://pub.dev/packages/freezed), it's a code generator for unions/pattern-matching/copy. The file of my application is `66053795.shuffle.dart` and the file generated by Freezed is `66053795.shuffle.freezed.dart`. Explanation about the  part` keyword: https://livebook.manning.com/book/dart-in-action/chapter-5/point-9613-147-147-0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a GlobalKey.

It feels pretty inelegant. It surprises me that with the close relationship between the widget and its state object, there's no easy way for a widget's method to call a method on the SO.  The "widget.blah" construct provides a way for the SO to access the widget's data, is there a reason for not having a similar "state.myMethod" construct?

Anyway, the following works:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<Block> g_blocks = [Block(Colors.red), Block(Colors.green),
  Block(Colors.blue), Block(Colors.purple)];
GlobalKey g_key = GlobalKey();
Rack g_rack = new Rack(key: g_key);

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// This widget is the root of your application.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'PressStart',
      ),
      home: MyHomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  createState() => MyHomeScreenState();
}

class MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Thanks for your help')),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: g_rack,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
        height: 100.0,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: 0,
          iconSize: 48.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[100],
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Shuffle',
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Shuffle',
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (int index) {
            g_blocks.shuffle();
            g_key.currentState.setState(() {
            });
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }   // build
}   // End class MyHomeScreenState

class Rack extends StatefulWidget {
  Rack({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _rackState createState() => _rackState();
}

class _rackState extends State<Rack> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150.0,
      color: Colors.yellow[200],
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: g_blocks),
    );
  }
  void updateRack(){
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  Block(this.color);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(height:50,width:50, color: color,);
  }
}
```